# Don't understand a seg fault

Tags: c++, pointers, segmentation-fault

String is my own string class and Stack is my own stack class. 
I am trying to change infix to postfix with values that are separated by spaces.

The function below pretty much works but also returns a "Segmentation fault (core dumped)".

```
String postfix(String infix){
    std::vector<String> vec;
    vec = infix.split(' ');
    Stack<String> tmp;
    String right, left, op;

    int i = 0;
    while (vec[i] != ';'){
        if (vec[i] == ')'){
            right = tmp.pop();
            op = tmp.pop();
            left = tmp.pop();
            tmp.push(left + ' ' + right + ' ' + op);
        }else{
            if (vec[i] != '(' && vec[i] != ' ')
            tmp.push(vec[i]);
        }
        ++i;
    }

    String postfix = tmp.pop();
    return postfix;
}
```

I do not understand why this is. Any help would be appreciated.

```
#ifndef STACK_HPP
#define STACK_HPP

template <typename T>
class Node{
public:
  T data;
  Node<T>* next;
  Node() {  data().next(0); } ;
  Node (const T& x) : data (x), next(0) {};
};


template <typename T>
class Stack{

public:
  Stack() : tos(0){};
  ~Stack();
  Stack(const Stack<T>&);
  void swap(Stack<T>& rhs);
  Stack<T>& operator= (Stack<T> rhs) { swap(rhs); return *this; };
  bool isEmpty() const { return tos == 0; };
  T pop();
  void push(const T&);

private:
  Node<T> *tos;
};

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

template <typename T>
Stack<T>::~Stack(){
  while(tos != 0){
    Node<T> *tmp = tos;
    tos = tos -> next;
    delete tmp;
  }
}

template <typename T>
void Stack<T>::swap(Stack<T>& rhs){
  Node<T> *tmp = tos;
  tos = rhs.tos;
  rhs.tos = tmp;
}

template <typename T>
Stack<T>::Stack(const Stack<T>& actual){
  Node<T> *tmp = actual.tos, *bottom = 0;
  tos = 0;
  while (tmp != 0){
    if(tos == 0){
      tos = new Node<T>(tmp -> data);
      bottom = tos;
    }else{
      bottom -> next = new Node<T>(tmp -> data);
      bottom = bottom -> next;
    }
    tmp = tmp -> next;
  }
}

template<typename T>
T Stack<T>::pop(){
  T result = tos -> data;
  Node<T> *tmp = tos;
  tos = tos -> next;
  delete tmp;
  return result;
}

template <typename T>
void Stack<T>::push(const T& x){
  Node<T> *tmp = new Node<T> (x);
  tmp -> next = tos;
  tos = tmp;
}

#endif


//bruce pucci
//string
//cs23001
#include <iostream>
#include <cassert>
#include <vector>
#include <fstream>
#include "string.hpp"

///////////////////////////////string class friend functions////////////////////////
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
////////////////////////////////////I/O/////////////////////////////////////////////
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const String& print){//std::cout operator
  int i = 0;
  while (print.arr[i] > 0){
    out << print.arr[i];
    ++i;
  }
  return out;
}
std::ifstream& operator>>(std::ifstream& in, String& rhs){//ifstream operator.
  char tmp[stringSize];//grabs word by word (chars serperated by whitespace).
  in >> tmp;
  rhs = String(tmp);
  return in;
}
////////////////////////////////string class public functions///////////////////////
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
/////////////////////////////////constructors///////////////////////////////////////
String::String(){//default constructor. default size
  arr = new char[stringSize];
  cap = stringSize;
  arr[0] = 0;
}
String::String(const char a){//char constructor. default size
  arr = new char[stringSize];
  cap = stringSize;
  arr[0] = a;
  arr[1] = 0;
}
String::String(const char a[]){//char array constructor. default size
  arr = new char[stringSize];
  cap = stringSize;
  int i = 0;
  while (a[i] > 0){
    arr[i] = a[i];
    ++i;
  }
  arr[i] = 0;
}
String::String(const int initSize, const char a[]){//char array constructor. size passed as a parameter
  arr = new char[initSize];
  cap = initSize;
  int i = 0;
  while (a[i] > 0){
    arr[i] = a[i];
    ++i;
  }
  arr[i] = 0;
}
String::String(int initSize){//like default constructor. size passed as parameter
  arr = new char[initSize];
  cap = initSize;
}
//////////////////////////////////dynamic stuff/////////////////////////////////////////////////
String::String(const String& rhs){//big three. copy constructor
  arr = new char[rhs.cap];
  cap = rhs.cap;
  for (int i = 0; i < cap; ++i)
    arr[i] = rhs.arr[i];
}
String::~String(){//big three. destuctor.
  delete [] arr;
}
String& String::operator=(String rhs){//big three. assignment operator.
  swap(rhs);
  return *this;
}
String String::swap(String& rhs){//swap the pointers on 2 char arrays.
  int tmpCap = rhs.cap;
  rhs.cap = cap;
  cap = tmpCap;
  char* tmp = rhs.arr;
  rhs.arr = arr;
  arr = tmp;
  return *this;
}

///////////////////////////////////functions////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
void String::reallocate(int a){//changes the size of a dynamic String. size passed as parameter.
  String tmp;
  tmp.cap = a;
  tmp.arr = new char[a];//allocate space of size passed.
  int i = 0;
  while (arr[i] != 0){//copy elements to newly allocated tmp array
    tmp.arr[i] = arr[i];
    ++i;
  }
  tmp.arr[i] = 0;
  swap(tmp);//swap pointers of tmp and passed array
}
std::vector<String> String::split(char splitter) const{//splits a String into a vecotr of
  std::vector<String> vecOfStrings;//Strings besed on the delimited passed
  int start = 0, end = 0;//returns that vector
  bool doIt = false;
  for (int i = 0; i < cap; ++i){//look if the delimiter exists
    if (arr[i] == ' '){
      doIt = true;
      break;
    }
  }
  if (doIt){//if the delimiter exists in the string start looping
    for (int i = 0; i < cap; ++i){
      if (arr[i] == splitter){//when each occurance of the delimiter is found create a
    end = i;//node of String in the vector with the chars since the previous node
    vecOfStrings.push_back(substr(start, end - 1));
    start = (end + 1);
      }
      if (i == (cap - 1)){//do this until the no more delimiters are found
    end = i;
    vecOfStrings.push_back(substr(start, end));
      }
    }
  }
  return vecOfStrings;
}
int String::length() const{//returns the length of the String before the terminating char.
  int counter = 0;
  while (arr[counter] != 0)
    ++counter;
  return counter;
}
int String::capacity() const{//accessor to capacity.
  return cap;
}
String String::substr(int start, int end) const{//returns a subset string of string passed.
  if ((start < 0) || (end < 0))//parameters are starting and ending points of the substring
    return String();
  String result;
  int returnIndex = start;
  for (int i = start; i <= end; ++i)
    result[i - start] = arr[returnIndex++];
  result[end - start + 1] = 0;
  return result;
}
int String::findChar(const char target) const{//returns the position of the first occurance of the char
  for (int i = 0; i < length(); ++i)//being searched for. returns -1 if the char is not found.
    if (arr[i] == target)
      return i;
  std::cout << "The char was not found." << std::endl;
  return -1;
}
int String::findStr(const char target[]) const{//searches for a substring in the string. returns the
  String targetString(target);//position of the first char in the substring
  return findStr(targetString);//uses the String version of findStr. look there for more info.
}
int String::findStr(const String& target) const{//searches for a substring in the string. returns the
  int targetLength = target.length();//position of the first char in the substring
  String candidate;//candidate is the string that
  int candStart = 0, candEnd = candStart + (targetLength - 1), i = 0;//will be compared to other strings
  //of the same length
  while (i < (stringSize - targetLength)){//go through char by char and compare candidate to
    candidate = substr(candStart++, candEnd++);//strings of the same length within the full string.
    if (candidate == target)//ex String = "Hello World." looking for "llo"
      return i;//"Hel" == "llo" no "Hel" == "ell" no "llo == "llo" yes.
    i++;//return 2.
  }
  std::cout << "The string was not found." << std::endl;
  return -1;//if not found at all return -1
}
int String::stringToInt(){
  int result = 0, intTmp;
  char charTmp;
  for (int i = 0; i < length(); ++i){
    charTmp = arr[i];
    switch (charTmp){
    case '0' : intTmp = 0; break;
    case '1' : intTmp = 1; break;
    case '2' : intTmp = 2; break;
    case '3' : intTmp = 3; break;
    case '4' : intTmp = 4; break;
    case '5' : intTmp = 5; break;
    case '6' : intTmp = 6; break;
    case '7' : intTmp = 7; break;
    case '8' : intTmp = 8; break;
    case '9' : intTmp = 9; break;
    case '-' : intTmp = 0; break;
    }
    if (result > 0)
      result = result * 10;
    result = result + intTmp;
  }
  return result;
}

/////////////////////////////////////////////operators////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
char String::operator[](int i) const{//subscript operator. returns char whated in char array. const version.
  return arr[i];//acts as an accessor to chars
}
char& String::operator[](int i){//subscript operator. returns char whated in char array. non const version.
  return arr[i];//acts as an accessor to chars
}
String String::operator+(const String& rhs) const{//concatenate
  String result(arr);
  int start = length(), rhsIndex = 0;
  while (rhs.arr[rhsIndex] != 0){
    result.arr[start] = rhs.arr[rhsIndex];
    start++;
    rhsIndex++;
  }
  result.arr[start] = 0;
  return result;
}
bool String::operator==(const String& rhs) const{
  if (length() != rhs.length())
    return false;
  for (int i = 0; i < length(); ++i)
    if (arr[i] != rhs.arr[i])
      return false;
  return true;
}
bool String::operator!=(const String& rhs) const{
  if (*this == rhs)
    return false;
  return true;
}

bool String::operator<(const String& rhs) const{
  int i = 0;
  while (arr[i] != 0 && rhs.arr[i] != 0){
    if ((arr[i] - rhs.arr[i]) < 0)
      return true;
    else if ((arr[i] - rhs.arr[i]) > 0)
      return false;
    i++;
  }
  if (length() < rhs.length())
    return true;
  return false;
}
bool String::operator>(const String& rhs) const{
  if (*this == rhs)
    return false;
  if (*this < rhs)
    return false;
  return true;
}
bool String::operator<=(const String& rhs) const{
  if (*this == rhs)
    return true;
  if (*this < rhs)
    return true;
  return false;
}
bool String::operator>=(const String& rhs) const{
  if (*this == rhs)
    return true;
  if (*this < rhs)
    return false;
  return true;
}

//////////////////////////////free functions////////////////////////////////
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
///////////////they use the public functions of the String class////////////
String operator+(const char lhs[], const String& rhs){
  String lhsString(lhs);
  String result = lhsString + rhs;
  return result;
}
String operator+(const char lhs, const String& rhs){
  String lhsString(lhs);
  String result = lhsString + rhs;
  return result;
}
bool operator==(const char lhs[], const String& rhs){
  String lhsString(lhs);
  return lhsString == rhs;
}
bool operator==(const char lhs, const String& rhs){
  String lhsString(lhs);
  return lhsString == rhs;
}
bool operator!=(const char lhs[], const String& rhs){
  String lhsString(lhs);
  return lhsString != rhs;
}
bool operator!=(const char lhs, const String& rhs){
  String lhsString(lhs);
  return lhsString != rhs;
}
bool operator<(const char lhs[], const String& rhs){
  String lhsString(lhs);
  return lhsString < rhs;
}
bool operator<(const char lhs, const String& rhs){
  String lhsString(lhs);
  return lhsString < rhs;
}
bool operator>(const char lhs[], const String& rhs){
  String lhsString(lhs);
  return lhsString > rhs;
}
bool operator>(const char lhs, const String& rhs){
  String lhsString(lhs);
  return lhsString > rhs;
}
bool operator<=(const char lhs[], const String& rhs){
  String lhsString(lhs);
  return lhsString <= rhs;
}
bool operator<=(const char lhs, const String& rhs){
  String lhsString(lhs);
  return lhsString <= rhs;
}
bool operator>=(const char lhs[], const String& rhs){
  String lhsString(lhs);
  return lhsString >= rhs;
}
bool operator>=(const char lhs, const String& rhs){
  String lhsString(lhs);
  return lhsString >= rhs;
}
```

I've added some to the code for debugging purposes. The 6 never appears.

```
String postfix(String infix){
  std::vector<String> vec;
  vec = infix.split(' ');
  Stack<String> tmp;
  String right, left, op;

  int i = 0;
  while (vec[i] != ';'){
    std::cout << 1 << std::endl;
    if (vec[i] == ')'){
      right = tmp.pop();
      op = tmp.pop();
      left = tmp.pop();
      std::cout << 2 << std::endl;
      tmp.push(left + ' ' + right + ' ' + op);
      std::cout << 3 << std::endl;
    }else{
      if (vec[i] != '(' && vec[i] != ' ')
        std::cout << 4 << std::endl;
        tmp.push(vec[i]);
        std::cout << 5 << std::endl;
    }
    ++i;
  }

  std::cout << 6 << std::endl;
  String postfix = tmp.pop();
  return postfix;
}
```

Output is

-bash-4.1$ make tests
g++ -g -Wall -W -Wunused -Wuninitialized -Wshadow  -iquote . -iquote ../string -c test_data3.cpp
g++ -g -Wall -W -Wunused -Wuninitialized -Wshadow  string.o test_data3.o -o test_data3
./test_intStack
Everything looks good. Done testing an int Stack.
./test_stringStack
Everything looks good. Done testing a String Stack.
./test_data3
( AX + ( B * C ) ) ;
1
5
1
4
5
1
4
5
1
5
1
4
5
1
4
5
1
4
5
1
2
3
1
2
3
1
4
5
make: *** [tests] Segmentation fault (core dumped)
rm test_data3.o

Comment: How are you sure that i is less than the size of vec?

Comment: w/o the details of String and Stack, getting help, will be challenging

Comment: @carlosdc all inputs end with ';'

Comment: @BrucePucci actually it needs to end with space and then a ;

Comment: @MarkHendrickson What details would be needed? They are fairly lengthy classes.

Comment: The class String seems pretty important to your code. Perhaps start with operator!=(char) and split.

Comment: lacking quite a bit of detail, like which exact line of code is causing the seg fault. is it inside of Stack or String? std::vector? etc

Comment: Sorry, This is my first post getting the hang of it on the fly here. Let me try to find that info.

Comment: You seem to be doing this in a complicated way. Why not have two stacks or a stack and a queue and put operands in the queue *always*, operators go onto one or the other based on math precedence. I wouldn't even bother splitting the string, MO of course, anyhow when you're done the queue will be in the proper order for evaluation after you unload the remaining elements in the stack.

Comment: plz post the code of your stack and string that are your classes

Comment: @BobbyDigital Thank you I will work on that. I haven't written a queue yet but will do so soon. We can't use stl things except for a few I/O things and vector in my CS class.

Comment: `Node() {  data().next(0); } ;` - what is that supposed to mean? What were you trying to do by this?

Comment: @AndreyT Constructor initializing the linked list pointer to next Node as 0. Supposed to be a comma instead of a period. Thank you.

Comment: If it is any help it runs with correct output on Code::Blocks IDE on Linux but not on a Unix system with a G++ compiler. Code::Blocks does say segmentation fault after the correct output is written though.

Comment: @Bruce Pucci: "Initializing"? You cannot *initialize* anything inside the body of constructor, you can only *assign* to things in there. Initialization is done in *constructor initializer list*, which is placed *before* the body of constructor. You got it right with your second constructor (the one that you are actually using), so apparently you know how to do it properly. How come you did this one completely wrong? The code I quoted makes no sense. Replacing the period with a comma won't save it.

Comment: @AndreyT Ok, I will fix it. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

You almost certainly want to start by isolating the problem.

To do that, I'd start by doing a bit of rewriting to use your own code for the postfix conversion itself, but use `std::string` and `std::stack` for the string and stack type respectively.

If that makes the problem disappear, switch one (but *not* both) back to use your class. If it still works, switch the other to use your class.

Chances are very good that this will fairly quickly tell you whether the problem is in your postfix-conversion, your Stack, or your String. Once you've figured that out, I'd *probably* work at writing some decent unit tests for the component in question.

You *could* just debug it in context instead, but chances are pretty fair (at least in my experience) that doing so will often leave a number of similar problems, so the next time you try to use it, you'll run into similar problems under slightly different circumstances. By working at it more systematically you can eliminate entire classes of bugs instead of removing them one at a time.

Comment: Thank you. I will work on finding the problem more systematically. It's just the Segmentation Fault with no line of where the error occurred is a little vague for a newbie.

Comment: Then you need to attach gdb. `gdb -tui myappname` will give you a nice text-based GUI for GDB.